# Return of a trait that is implemented by two structs based on predefined string format

Tags: rust

I am struggling with returning a common trait, given lines I have currently:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct GroupAddressThreeLevel {
    main: u8,
    middle: u8,
    sub: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct GroupAddressTwoLevel {
    main: u8,
    sub: u16,
}

pub trait GroupAddressBytes {
    fn as_bytes(&self) -> [u8; 2];
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; 2]) -> Result<Self, CustomError> where Self : Sized;
}


impl GroupAddressBytes for GroupAddressThreeLevel {
    pub fn new(main: u8, middle: u8, sub: u8) -> Result<Self, CustomError> {
       ... omitted ...
    }
}

impl GroupAddressBytes for GroupAddressTwoLevel {
    pub fn new(main: u8, sub: u16) -> Result<Self, CustomError> {
       ... omitted ...
    }
}

impl GroupAddress {
    pub fn parse(address: &str) -> Result<dyn GroupAddressBytes, CustomError> {

        let splitted_address: Vec<_> = address.split('/').collect();
        match splitted_address.len() {
            3 => {
                // Group Address is Three-level
                GroupAddressThreeLevel::new(
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[0]).unwrap(),
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[1]).unwrap(),
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[2]).unwrap(),
                )
           }
            2 => {
                // Group Address is Two-Level
                GroupAddressTwoLevel::new(
                    u8  ::from_str(splitted_address[0]).unwrap(),
                    u16::from_str(splitted_address[1]).unwrap(),
                )
            }
            _ => {
                Err(CustomError(format!("Unsupported address format provided. Supported are: 0/0/0 or 0/0")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am getting from compiler is:

```
37  |     pub fn parse(address: &str) -> Result<dyn GroupAddressBytes, CustomError> {
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
```

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety it seems be object safe as I added "Self : Sized" to the method of GroupAddressBytes trait.

How can I accomplish that `GroupAddress#parse(&str)` function will compile successfully and return the `GroupAddressBytes` as an object?

The idea of `GroupAddress#parse(&str)` function is when user provides format "0/0/0" then `GroupAddressThreeLevel` is returned, if "0/0" is provided then `GroupAddressTwoLevel` is returned. Both structs will have their own implementation which varies bit differently, but share the same methods provided by `GroupAddressBytes`.

---

Alternatively, if the approach above is not possible with Rust, what about following approach. Here I also failed:

```
    pub fn parse<T : GroupAddressBytes>(address: &str) -> Result<T, CustomError> {
```

which returns by compiler:

```
 expected type parameter `T`, found struct `GroupAddressThreeLevel`
 expected type parameter `T`, found struct `GroupAddressTwoLevel`
```

Thank you, Christoph

Comment: `dyn Trait` values have to always be behind some sort of reference. In your case `Box`ing them will work.

Comment: Thanks. `Result<Box<dyn GroupAddressBytes>, CustomError>` solved the issue. I could not use the `impl` keyword as it is returning either of `GroupAddressThreeLevel` or `GroupAddressTwoLevel` which is complained by compiler. So I had to unwrap the value from e.g. `GroupAddressThreeLevel::new` and wrap it into a Box as suggested.

Comment: Additional to comment before (might helpful for others): Solved by e.g.
`match GroupAddressThreeLevel::new(
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[0]).unwrap(),
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[1]).unwrap(),
                    u8::from_str(splitted_address[2]).unwrap(),
                ) {
                    Ok(group_address) => Ok(Box::new(group_address)),
                    Err(e) => Err(e)
                }`